# Create EditText as the entered value

Tags: android, android-edittext

The user will input a number. How can I create that number of `EditText` boxes using JAVA code?

Comment: user enters a number, for example 5 and you want to create 5 textboxes. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this --->

```
createMultipleEditTexts(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        // Assign id for future reference probably store it somewhere
        et.setId(i)

        // Assign layout params to it
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height)
        et.setParams(params)

        // Add it to the root layout of your activity's/view groups view
        rootLayout.addView(et);
    }
}
```

call the above code from onCreate() of your activity after you've taken in n from the user

Comment: Gives error. (In LinearLayout and rootlayout line).

Comment: Depends on the type of your root layout. That is if you're activity's root layout is linear layout use LinearLayout.LayoutParams else if it's RelativeLayout use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams